# Most Likely Number of Winners - Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming, probability-theory

You are given a team's win probability for each game on their schedule in the form P[1..n] where P[i] is the likelihood they win game i. Give a dynamic programming algorithm that returns the most likely number of wins, and the probability of this outcome, using O(n) space.

For example, if n = 2 and P = [0.4, 0.2], the most likely number of wins is 0, with a probability of .6 ∗ .8 = .48 (P(1) = .4*.8+.6*.2 = .44 and P(2) = .4 * .2 = .08).

I understand how to do this manually: if I want to find P(x) wins I add up the probabilities of the outcomes that result in x wins. Is there an algorithmic way of doing this more efficiently?

My first instinct was to construct an array R such that R[i] is the probability your team wins i games. The only computation this saves you though is if you have a max element greater than the remaining probability possible (if n = 5 and R(0) = .4 and R(1) = .3, you know that none of the elements R[2:5] are going to be the max).

My second thought is to define the subproblem so that we only add i to the list if P(i) > P(i - 1), so that we're effectively keeping a running max probability. Again though, I know I'm not making use of the overlapping subproblems, I'm re-calculating the probability for each i.

It seems there must be method to calculate P(i) based on the previously-calculated values. If we think about it top-down, we could calculate P(n) = 1-P(n-1). I don't see how this generalizes to elements other than the last one though. Am I missing something fundamental re: probability calculation?

Comment: Can you credit the original source where you encountered this task?

Comment: We have tips on how to approach dynamic programming algorithms here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info.  I suggest trying them and then editing your question to show your progress so far.  Can you find an exponential-time recursive algorithm?